# How to get the css value of transform directly using jquery that witch set as percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I  am set transform: translate(200%, 700%);

when i try to read it by code below it take me this valuse as px :

```
calculateAllowed = function (obj) {
        var matrix = $(obj).css('transform');
        alert(matrix);
        var values = matrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var x = values[4];
        alert(x);
};
```

x is an integer number

I expect to get 200 or "200%".
How can i get it as percent that i set first time?

Comment: the only way to obtain raw CSS declaration is via the Stylesheet api, exposed via `document.styleSheets`. You need then to filter for the right `CSSStyleSheet` to deal with before accessing its `CSSRules`, in each rule (which should be `CSSStyleRule`) you can filter for the right rule (by reading the `selectorText`, `cssText`). After finding the right rule, just access the property `style` and read everything exactly like how it's declared (raw text). Parsing is also required then. Anyway dealing with Stylesheets like this is usually to add some dynamic CSS.

Comment: You should re-consider your ***original*** issue to solve it right from there. Parsing the CSS for info like this is not reliable (when something will be changed in future ...) and at last it's not the purpose of CSS (info stored to render the page, not to be obtained to do something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(element).css('transform');
```

You can use:

If using javscript:

```
element.style.transform
```

Using Jquery:

```
$(element).style.transform
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jchadaxj/1/)

Snippet using Javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  var matrix = document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform;
  alert(matrix);
  var values = matrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
  alert(values);
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="transform: translate(20%, 70%)">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this works only for ***inline*** style, you can try it yourself with declared style (in `style` block,...).

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide it by the width and multiply it by 100 to get it in percent form.

```js
function calculateAllowed(obj) { //just for easy testing
        var matrix = $(obj).css('transform');
        console.log(matrix);
        var values = matrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var x = values[4];
        var end = x / $(obj).width() * 100;
        console.log(end);
};

calculateAllowed( $("div") )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="transform: translate(200%, 700%)" >afwe</div>
```